# Yii2 How disable Redis

Tags: redis, yii2

I made the deply of my application (Yii2) in the production environment of the client and there he uses REDIS in another application (Laravel).

However in my Yii2 application I have nothing using or instantiating REDIS, however when running the error appears below. How do I disable REDIS in the application?

[image]

Example web.php

```
    'session' => [
        'name' => '_siscoopSessionId',
        'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime', 
    ],       
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
```

**UPDATE**

My db.php

```
return [
    'class'     => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn'       => 'mysql:host=srv-probat;dbname=siscoop',
    'username'  => 'intranet',
    'password'  => '*****',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
];
```

Comment: are you using localhost as the host in the db connection?

Comment: Hi, i update with my db.php config

Comment: In my environment or localhost the error does not occur, only in the client's environment.

Comment: can you try using the ip address for the `host` ?

Comment: If you use advanced app u can override config via `-local` config files

Comment: Did not work. From what I perceived the client's environment records REDIS sessions, I will have to configure it in my application. Right?

Comment: I use the Basic app version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Remove all this code:

```
'session' => [
    'name' => '_appnameSessionId',
    'savePath' => DIR . '/../runtime', 
],       
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
],
```